# Pulseaudio audio problems

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

I have had this problem for quite some time now, before it worked by just inputting  `pulseaudio --start`, but now it doesn't work anymore. Usually when i use my web browser i start hearing crackling sounds, usually for the first 10 seconds of the audio playing it's fine, and then these noises begin, affecting not only the browser but the whole computer. I also tried reinstalling pulseaudio but the problem doesn't seem to go away.I'm on 20.04.03 LTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same and was able to fix it. It may be related to speech-dispatcher (some text-to-speech utility), so you can try:

```
killall speech-dispatcher
```

If the sound comes back to normal you can remove it completely (if you don't need it) with:

```
sudo apt remove speech-dispatcher
```

Don't forget to restart your web browser.

source: https://tqdev.com/2021-firefox-ubuntu-crackling-sound

Comment: Not happening anymore, but if it will happen again  i will try, thanks